# Left navigation link highlight issue in Modern team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, left-navigation

I have one site collection with modern team site template, which has different sub-sites created under that site. I have set hyperlinks of different sub-sites in left navigation of root site. I set these hyperlinks from left navigation manually.

Now, when I visit one sub-site, it would show that hyperlink in left navigation as highlighted one as per expected behavior, but for some of the sub-site links, it's not showing them highlighted, instead it highlights some other site's links in left navigation.

See attached image for reference, Currently, I have selected "Sales" site but it's highlighting on "Finance and HR".:

[image]

Let me know if there is any work around for this or is it a known issue in modern team site?

Comment: I have observed the similar issue previously on team sites.

Comment: I have done a  test in my SharePoint Online and i cannot reproduce your issue. what is the template of your sub site which met the issue?Does the issue exists in new experience or classic experience?

Comment: Sub-sites are created with modern UI team site template.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try to use other browser and compare the results.

Comment: I getting same issue with IE11, edge and chrome. I have noticed one thing that in this site I have external sharing on and due to that "Shared with Us" option is dynamically coming in left navigation. And I am getting this issue. Other site collection and in other tenant where this option is disabled, I am not getting this issue. Now, I have stopped external sharing in this site, and issue is still there.